# Is a bundler necessary even if targets are modern browsers that support ES modules?

Tags: javascript, html

Now modern browsers such as Chrome, Edge, Safari, Firefox, support ES modules.

So I am studying how to write sites and libraries for those browsers and I have a question of the title.

Is a bundler necessary even if targets are modern browsers that support ES modules?

Since those browsers support only file path, not package name in my understanding, I concluded that you need some bundler like Webpack or Rollup.js not only for old browsers but also those modern browsers.

Is my understanding right?

If so, it seems kind of strange for me that web standard technology depends on undefined bundler tools.
Is this situation temporary or not?

I guess that some registry will be standardized and you can import external modules directly from the registry in the future same as current script tags with CDN URLs.

Is my guess wrong?

Since I am being confused about ES modules, good summaries are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Even if a browser supports modules, it would be better to use a bundler so that you only serve *one* `.js` file rather than (for example) 100.

Comment: With HTTP2, the benefit of serving a single bundle can go away (or become detrimental).

Comment: Bundlers allow unused code to be eliminated from the bundle, reducing bundle size. Depending on the bundler they might add any one of a huge number of additional features including support for referencing different file types. Essentially a bundler gives you an opportunity to analyse, optimise or extend code in a way impossible using imports directly. Also remember node only includes experimental support for ES6 modules.

Comment: Bundles meant for browser and provide faster execution within the browser. If you'll serve those files via CDN, It'll be extra headache for browser to load that first. And of course modern browser supports this feature, imo.